# flutter: GridView not showing properly

Tags: flutter, dart, listview, gridview

i'm trying to create a restaurant menu app in flutter language, and i wanted to view my saved data inside json file as gridView but sadly i'm getting error while running the app.. However,  i tried to change the gridView to listView and its showing good..
so is there a way to show them as gridView?
thanks in advance

```js
[
  {
    "placeImage": "assets/images/wood.jpg",
    "placeName":  "The Hawkers",
    "placeItems": ["Burgers","Chinese","Fast Food","Italian","Juice"],
    "minOrder": 20
  },
  {
    "placeImage": "assets/images/wood.jpg",
    "placeName":  "Flipping Noodles",
    "placeItems": ["Burgers","Chinese","Fast Food","Italian","Juice"],
    "minOrder": 50
  },
  {
    "placeImage": "assets/images/wood.jpg",
    "placeName":  "Pizza Hut",
    "placeItems": ["Pizza","Chinese","Fast Food","Italian","Juice"],
    "minOrder": 20
  },
  {
    "placeImage": "assets/images/wood.jpg",
    "placeName":  "Blue Hill",
    "placeItems": ["Burgers","Chinese","Fast Food","Italian","Juice"],
    "minOrder": 40
  },
  {
    "placeImage": "imagess/bluehill.jpg",
    "placeName": "Blue Hill",
    "placeItems": ["Burgers","Chinese","Fast Food","Italian","Juice"],
    "minOrder": 40
  }
]
```

```html
import 'dart:convert';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:material_design_icons_flutter/material_design_icons_flutter.dart';

void main() => runApp(Breakfast());

class Breakfast extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

var bannerItems = ["Burger", "Cheese Chilly", "Noodles", "Pizza"];
var bannerImage = [
  "images/burger.jpg",
  "images/cheesechilly.jpg",
  "images/noodles.jpg",
  "images/pizza.jpg"
];

class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height;
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    Future<List<Widget>> createList() async {
      List<Widget> items = new List<Widget>();
      String dataString =
          await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context).loadString("assets/data.json");
      List<dynamic> dataJSON = jsonDecode(dataString);

      dataJSON.forEach((object) {
        String finalString = "";
        List<dynamic> dataList = object["placeItems"];
        dataList.forEach((item) {
          finalString = finalString + item + " | ";
        });

        items.add(Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(2.0),
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.white,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(10.0)),
                boxShadow: [
                  BoxShadow(
                      color: Colors.black12,
                      spreadRadius: 2.0,
                      blurRadius: 5.0),
                ]),
            margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
            child: Row(
              mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
              crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
              children: <Widget>[
                ClipRRect(
                  borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(10.0),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(10.0)),
                  child: Image.asset(
                    object["placeImage"],
                    width: 80,
                    height: 80,
                    fit: BoxFit.cover,
                  ),
                ),
                SizedBox(
                  width: 250,
                  child: Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                    child: Column(
                      crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                      children: <Widget>[
                        Text(object["placeName"]),
                        Padding(
                          padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 2.0, bottom: 2.0),
                          child: Text(
                            finalString,
                            overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                            style: TextStyle(
                              fontSize: 12.0,
                              color: Colors.black54,
                            ),
                            maxLines: 1,
                          ),
                        ),
                        Text(
                          "Min. Order: ${object["minOrder"]}",
                          style:
                              TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.black54),
                        )
                      ],
                    ),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
      });

      return items;
    }

    return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        height: screenHeight,
        width: screenWidth,
        child: SafeArea(
            child: SingleChildScrollView(
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(10, 5, 10, 5),
                child: Row(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.menu), onPressed: () {}),
                    Text(
                      "Foodies",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontFamily: "Samantha"),
                    ),
                    IconButton(icon: Icon(Icons.person), onPressed: () {})
                  ],
                ),
              ),
              BannerWidgetArea(),
              Container(
                child: FutureBuilder(
                    initialData: <Widget>[Text("")],
                    future: createList(),
                    builder: (context, snapshot) {
                      if (snapshot.hasData) {
                        return Padding(
                          padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                          child: GridView.count(
                            crossAxisCount: 3,
                            crossAxisSpacing: 4.0,
                            mainAxisSpacing: 2.0,
                            children: snapshot.data,
                          ),
                        );
                      } else {
                        return CircularProgressIndicator();
                      }
                    }),
              )
            ],
          ),
        )),
      ),
      floatingActionButton: FloatingActionButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          backgroundColor: Colors.black,
          child: Icon(
            MdiIcons.food,
            color: Colors.white,
          )),
    );
  }
}

class BannerWidgetArea extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var screenWidth = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    PageController controller =
        PageController(viewportFraction: 0.8, initialPage: 1);

    List<Widget> banners = new List<Widget>();

    for (int x = 0; x < bannerItems.length; x++) {
      var bannerView = Padding(
        padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
        child: Container(
          child: Stack(
            fit: StackFit.expand,
            children: <Widget>[
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    boxShadow: [
                      BoxShadow(
                          color: Colors.black38,
                          offset: Offset(2.0, 2.0),
                          blurRadius: 5.0,
                          spreadRadius: 1.0)
                    ]),
              ),
              ClipRRect(
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                child: Image.asset(
                  bannerImage[x],
                  fit: BoxFit.cover,
                ),
              ),
              Container(
                decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(20.0)),
                    gradient: LinearGradient(
                        begin: Alignment.topCenter,
                        end: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                        colors: [Colors.transparent, Colors.black])),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
                child: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.end,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                      bannerItems[x],
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 25.0, color: Colors.white),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      "More than 40% Off",
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 12.0, color: Colors.white),
                    )
                  ],
                ),
              )
            ],
          ),
        ),
      );
      banners.add(bannerView);
    }

    return Container(
      width: screenWidth,
      height: screenWidth * 9 / 16,
      child: PageView(
        controller: controller,
        scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
        children: banners,
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you include `json` to test it out?

Comment: @YeasinSheikh i added it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly I would prefer having data from `Future` instead of `<Widget>` and will avoid `forEach` method to handle complex and bigger computation.

Lets processed with current condition of code-structure. According to your question, main issue is using `ListView`/`GridView`.

While `SingleChildScrollView` is handling the scroll, use `GridView.count` or `ListView`

```dart
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
```

About the top level-column

```dart
 body: SafeArea(
          child: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
          mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, // set min
          children: <Widget>[
```

To check error, define states of `FutureBuilder`

```dart
 child: FutureBuilder<List<Widget>>(
                  initialData: [Text("")],
                  future: createList(context),
                  builder: (context, snapshot) {
                    if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting)
                      return Text("Loading");

                    if (snapshot.hasError) {
                      return Text("Error ${snapshot.error}");
                    }
                    if (snapshot.hasData) {
                      return Padding(
                        padding: EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                        child: GridView.count(
                         childAspectRatio: 1 // items' width/height
                          crossAxisCount: 3,
                          shrinkWrap: true,
                          physics: NeverScrollableScrollPhysics(),
                          children: [
                            ...snapshot.data!,
                          ],
                        ),
```

To load JSON, I've used like `String dataString = await rootBundle.loadString("json/data.json");`

To handle item size use `childAspectRatio`.

Assuming you don't have issue with loading images/`BannerWidgetArea()` widgets.

Does it solve the issue?

Comment: it did actually thanks !! :D